# strange behaviour of python format unicode/string method

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates, python-unicode

I'm having a problem displaying a variable in a template. I have a model with this `__unicode__` method:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):

...

def __unicode__(self):
    return 'Admisión para {student}'.format(student=self.student.__unicode__())  # Look at that accented char (ó)
```

In the top of my models.py file, i have these two lines:

```
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

I'm using python 2.7.3

The template that should show what i want is like this: (just the three interesting lines)

```
<td>{{obj}}</td>
<td>{{obj.status}}</td>
<td>{{obj.stage.datetime|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}}</td>
```

obj is an object of type "MyClass". The second and third line show what they were expected to, but the first line doesn't show anything. I know that when one do that ({{obj}}) the method called is "**unicode**", so i tried many things:

I try something similar but in the console: `print obj`. I didn't have any problem. It displayed as i expected.

I suspected that unicode method was raising an exception. So i change the method to be like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    try:
        txt = 'Admisión para {student}'.format(student=self.student.__unicode__())
    except Exception, e:
        txt = unicode(e)

    return txt
```

After that change, when the template is rendered, {{obj}} was shown as "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)", so as i supposed, it was raising an exception.

But the most strange behaviour of all was that, when i change **unicode** method to look like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    txt = self.student.__unicode__())
    return 'Admisión para {student}'.format(student=txt)
```

{{obj}} was shown as i expected to...

Can somebody tell me where is my error? is it a python/django template bug? or what?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Well, the exception is at position 25 -- so it's not that ó that is the problem.

Comment: Correct. It seems to be that the problem is with the student name, but it doesn't contain any special character, and char at position 25 is a 'S' or an 'E' (don't know if position 25 is string[25] or strnig[24])... And although any problem with chars, why does the last option works well? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: A side note: In general you should not generate strings in your models which should be displayed in templates. The whole point of templates is to separate presentation layer from business logic. You should generate the string for a template at template level - `<td>Admisión para {{obj.student.name}}</td>`. Or you can add a custom method `full_name()` which returns a full name string to your `Student` model. Then you can use `<td>Admisión para {{obj.student.full_name}}</td>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that and i always try to separate those two worlds, but using __unicode__ is the way django recommends to say how you want to show objects of a class. Have a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode

The field "student" is a foreign key to another model, that has that __unicode__ method defined as well